# A horrid-looking integral $\int_{0}^{5} \frac{\pi(1+\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}} )}{\sqrt{10}\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+x}} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$
> \mathbf{\mbox{Evaluate:}}\qquad
> \int_{0}^{5}  \frac{\pi(1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} )}{\sqrt{10}\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+x}} 
> \,\,\mathrm{d}x
> $$

This is a very ugly integral, but appears to have a very simple closed form of: $$\Gamma(\frac15)\Gamma(\frac45)$$ Mathematica can evaluate this integral, but WolframAlpha doesn't even give a correct numerical answer. I have tried many techniques on this integral but have not been able to crack it at all.

Any help on this integral would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ignore the pi, it has no role

Comment: Is $\pi$ a constant here or the $\pi(x)$ function that returns the number of primes less than $x$.

Comment: @Dr.MV $\pi$ is a constant. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The first thing to do would seem to be the substitution $u=\sqrt x$.

Comment: You can get parentheses (and other paired delimiters) to adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @Semiclassical It appears I placed a plus sign while writing the question where I shouldn't have. I apologize, it should now.

Comment: @Semiclassical Perhaps I am just using mathematica wrong: N[Gamma[4/5]*Gamma[1/5]] Gives me 5.3448

Comment: @Semiclassical Wow, I really am out of sorts today. I apologize. I've edited. In any case, it doesn't affect how I would evaluate the integral.

Comment: It works now, yes. To connect with what I stated in a (now deleted) comment, note that the gamma function satisfies Euler's reflection formula $\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)=\pi/\sin(\pi z)$. For the special case of $z=1/5$, this gives $\Gamma(1/5)\Gamma(4/5)=\pi/\sin(\pi/5)=\pi \sqrt{2 + 2/\sqrt{5}}$ which is what Mathematica obtains directly.

Comment: I am surely making an error, but if I put $u=\sqrt{x}+x$, I note that $u^{\prime}(x)=1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$, so the integral is easy to compute....

Comment: @Kelenner Yes, however when computing this integral I was more concerned with going straight to the gamma function expression, and didn't think about finding a more elementary closed form and then showing it is equal to gamma(1/5)*gamma(4/5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u = \sqrt{x} + x$.  Then we have
$$ \frac\pi{\sqrt{10}} \int_0^5 \frac{1 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}{\sqrt{\sqrt x + x}} \, dx = \frac\pi{\sqrt{10}} \int_0^{\sqrt{5}+5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \, du$$

If you want to be pedantic (and who doesn't?!) then we need to note that this is an **improper integral** because the integrand is not defined at the lower limit of integration.  Therefore:

\begin{align}
  \frac\pi{\sqrt{10}} \int_0^{\sqrt{5}+5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \, du
    &= \lim_{B\to0^+}\frac\pi{\sqrt{10}} \int_B^{\sqrt{5}+5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\, du \\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{10}} \lim_{B \to 0^+} \sqrt{u}\bigg|_B^{\sqrt5 + 5} \\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{10}} \lim_{B\to0^+} \left(\sqrt{\sqrt5 + 5} - \sqrt B\right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{10}} \left(\sqrt{\sqrt5 + 5} - 0\right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{2\pi\sqrt{\sqrt5 + 5}}{\sqrt{10}}
\end{align}

Comment: You are confusing the word "pedantic" with rigorous.  They are not the same.  In fact, "pedantic" is a negative connotation.

Comment: @Dr.MV, It was intended to be read with mild sarcasm, but such things are usually difficult to detect in text written by strangers.

Comment: I did detect that tone (the "?!" sign was a clue).  But, this is a math site.  So, the word pedantic is quite an inappropriate choice for simply proceeding with rigor.

Comment: My English is poor, but that GREAT u-sub is all that it took and after the first line I just stopped reading. The question was solved for me. A classic example that this horrid looking integral took me for a spin, and I fell for it...

Comment: @Dr.MV, I know, hence the sarcasm.  That's why I didn't and wouldn't use pedantic as a *serious* substitute for rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

1. Substitute $x = u^2$. You end up with a denominator that contains $\sqrt{u + u^2}$.
2. Complete the square under the radical to $\sqrt{ u^2 + u + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}} = \sqrt{ (u+\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4}}$.
3. Substitute $z = 2(u+\frac{1}{2})$, so that $u + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{z}{2}$, and simplify.

Then do a trig substitution on the resulting term under the radical to get rid of the radical, and you should be on your way.

**Post-comment addendum:**

To convert the result (say from @Hrhm's answer) to gamma-function form, use [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula), which tells you that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{5}) \Gamma(\frac{4}{5}) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \frac{
\pi}{5}}$.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following site: 
http://www.integral-calculator.com/

First substitute $u=x+\sqrt{x}$

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+1$

The integral then becomes $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{10}}\int_{0}^{5+\sqrt{5}}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}$

This is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{2\pi\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{10}}\Bigg|^{5+\sqrt{5}}_{0}=\frac{2\pi\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{10}}\approx 5.34$

Comment: Thank you, but from here how can we show that the result you got is equal to my gamma function expression?

Comment: See post-comment addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$u=\sqrt{x}$, we have
$$
\int_{0}^{5}  \frac{\pi(1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} )}{\sqrt{10}\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+x}} 
\,\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{10}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{5}}  \frac{2u+1} {\sqrt{u+u^2}}du=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{10}}\sqrt{u^2+u}\Big{|}_{0}^{\sqrt{5}}
$$